# Aspiration versus C+h cluster

Tags: phonology, aspiration

Since there are languages with consonant clusters and languages with aspirated consonants, in principle there could be a language that has a surface contrast between [Ch] and [Cʰ]. Word-internally it might be possible to treat any such surface distinction as distinctive syllabification, i.e. [VC.hV] versus [V.ChV], but a surface contrast between #thV and #tʰV, or Vth# and Vtʰ# would provide pretty reasonable prima facia evidence for a contrast between a sequence versus a unit phoneme. I don't know of any language that has such a contrast – is such a language attested?

Comment: Is there some special quality about aspiration that is important here? Clusters of various sorts fall together with complex phonemes all the time in all kinds of languages.

Comment: Long story, it's analogous to kw vs kʷ. I'm fairly sure I encountered a contrast in Lushootseed, where the cue was when the labialization starts. The ultimate question is approximately, "can one ever justify such a difference within a language based solely on pronunciation?"

Comment: Distinctive aspiration in Lushootseed? On what phones?

Comment: No, rounding... *analogous*. kw:kʷ::kh:kʰ. I have the kw/kʷ part filled in, Im'm looking for the aspiration analogs.

Comment: Lushootseed individual variation is pretty frequent between front and back velars; there are /ts/ and /c/ which are distinguishable morphological but probly not phonologically, now that there are no more native speakers.

Comment: PIE also seems to have distinguished kw & kʷ, although most descendants merged the two

Comment: You know that in Khmer, what appear to be aspirated consonants are treated as Ch sequences because the C and the h can be broken up by an infix? I understand though that this always happens, and would assume that there is no contrastive aspiration on the C you are left with (otherwise, why treat all aspirated consonants as sequences in the first place?) On that basis you might say that if you were going to find your contrast anywhere, it would be in Khmer, and you don't. Not that that proves anything, strictly speaking.

Comment: I believe (based purely on Wikipedia) that the same thing happens in Semai, but it might be worth looking at other languages in the same family, and more generally, infixation might be a useful tell.

Answer (score 1):

It has been proposed that this contrast (aspiration vs. cluster consonant + [h]) does **not** exist (Kehrein & Golston 2004). The formal explanation is that aspiration is a property of the onset, not of individual segments. So, in an onset aspiration can occur once and it may be realized on the stop or as an [h] (or variably as both), but a contrast is not possible.

Comment: codas can also be aspirated. I'm not sure how this analysis handles cases of a coda immediately preceding an onset (i.e. whether it's onsets & codas that have the property of aspiration, or clusters, which may consist of both coda and onset)

Comment: Phonologically, it's prosodic categories (onset, nucleus, coda) that have aspiration, but phonetically assimilation between these units may take place, so that they agree for aspiration on the surface

Answer (score 1):

If you allow for clusters across syllable boundaries, English could be an example

what hand = /wɒt.hænd/
what and = /wɒtʰ.ænd/